# Access Store From Initializer in ember-cli

Tags: ember-cli

I have an initializer and the following is coming back as undefined:

container.lookup('store:main')

I am trying to implement this: http://say26.com/using-rails-devise-with-ember-js

Has anybody any ideas why this is?

Comment: Ok, so after some digging, you have to add to the initializer the following property: after: 'store' so that the store gets injected before this runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a code snippet on how I was able to inject the store into all components.

```js
//initializers/general-setup.js
import Ember from 'ember';

//The intent of this file is to hold initializers
//that are general and lack specific context or scope
export default {
    name: 'general-setup',
    after: 'store',
    initialize: function(container) {
        container.injection('component', 'store', 'store:main');

    }
};
```